Get users with created_after param as a regular user from Gitlab api
I'm trying to get users created after some DateTime according to Gitlab documentation, but nothing changes with changing parameters created_after or created_before. The documentation says that I (as a regular user without admin rights) am able to do it even if the created_at value is unavalible for me in get request.
My code:
url = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users?'

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {personal_tocken}'}
params = { 'per_page': 100, "without_project_bots": True, "created_after": '2024-09-01T00:00:00'}
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=params)
print(*request.json(),sep='\n')

I've tried to set created_after as '2025-09-01T00:00:00', but it still gets all users.
Is it possible to filter users by the created_at date as a regular user or do I have to be an admin for this?
